# expand all column simultaneously using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

expanding all columns in a spreadsheet simultaneously using Power Query. I have transposed the spreadsheet from this:

transposed column : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZnnY.png)

expand one column : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf9Rp.png)

expand all column : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3FYk.png)

after excpand column its create duplicate data

currently i am using this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"instrument_key", "Symbol1"}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Symbol.1", each Symbol([Symbol1])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"symbol", "year", "W/M", "Strike", "Option", "Symbol1", "tradingsymbol", "Lot"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns")
in
    #"Transposed Table"
```

i am expecting expand all column one by one witout duplicates like this

out put like this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR0R1.png)

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please toggle the checkmark by the answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 2):

If there are always 3 columns and a single row, and you begin with Source then

```
ColNames =Table.ColumnNames(Source{0}[Column1])& List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source{0}[Column2]), each _&"_2")& List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source{0}[Column3]), each _&"_3"),
Combined = Table.ToColumns(Source{0}[Column1]) & Table.ToColumns(Source{0}[Column2]) & Table.ToColumns(Source{0}[Column3]),
Expand=Table.FromColumns(Combined,ColNames)
```

[image]